# How to construct base change of cohomology map $H^n(Y,\mathcal{F})\to H^n(X,f^*\mathcal{F})$?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories, sheaf-cohomology, etale-cohomology

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, let $\mathcal{F}$ be an abelian sheaf on $Y$, in some topology $\tau$, safely speaking we assume it is the Zariski topology but it shouldn't really matter.

We further assume $f^*:\mathcal{Sh}(Y)\to \mathcal{Sh}(X)$ is exact. Can we easily deduce a map:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\H}{H} \H^n(Y,\mathcal{F})\to\H^n(X,f^*\mathcal{F})?$$

I would prefer a down to earth map, from the definition of cohomology but not using some Lerry spectral sequence abstract nonsense.

My plan of proof:

Consider an injective resolution $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{I}^\bullet$, and by exactness we have an resolution $f^*\mathcal{F}\to f^*\mathcal{I}^\bullet$, and if somehow we have that $f^*$ sends injectives to $\Gamma(X,\cdot)$-acyclic sheaves. Then we can calculate cohomology groups with $f^*\mathcal{I}^\bullet$, i.e. $\H^n(X,f^*\mathcal{F})=\H^n(f^*\mathcal{I}(X))$.

There is a map of complexes of sheaves:
$$\mathcal{I}^\bullet\to f_*f^*\mathcal{I}^\bullet$$
apply the global section function we have
$$\mathcal{I}^\bullet (Y)\to f_*f^*\mathcal{I}^\bullet (Y)=f^*\mathcal{I}^\bullet (X)$$
which induces a map of cohomology groups
$$\H^n(X,f^*\mathcal{F})=\H^n(f^*\mathcal{I}(X))$$
So the problem reduces to do we have that $f^*$ sends injectives to $\Gamma(X,\cdot)$-acyclic sheaves when $f^*$ is exact?

I assume this statement is true since I saw it on J. Milnes' book, "Etale Cohomology", pg 85, in his statement he uses etale topology but the idea should be the same for any topology.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330977/canonical-morphism-hny-f-mathscrf-to-hnx-mathscrf-in-sheaf/2332241#2332241 ?